# How to circumvent faulty doctrine ORM paging

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, pagination, symfony-2.8

I am using symfony 2.8.39 and Doctrine 2.4.8 and have problems with paged results. Underlying is an Mysql5.7 server.

The documentation on doctrine paging says:

> Paginating Doctrine queries is not as simple as you might think in the
>   beginning. If you have complex fetch-join scenarios with one-to-many
>   or many-to-many associations using the "default" LIMIT functionality
>   of database vendors is not sufficient to get the correct results.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

This is exactly the situation I have. My statement in SQL translation looks like this:

```
SELECT sc.id, sc.name, scc.prio, sd.description
FROM sang_contents sc
JOIN sang_categories_contents scc
JOIN sang_descriptions sd
JOIN sang_languages sl
WHERE
    sc.id = scc.content_id AND 
    scc.category_id = 20 AND
    scc.is_enabled = 1 AND
    sc.id = sd.content_id AND
    sd.language_id = sl.id AND
    sd.description != "" AND
    sl.name = "DE"
ORDER BY scc.prio ASC, sc.id DESC
```

As ORM is at Version 3.0 and this problem exists since the beginning I don't think it will be fixed anytime by ORM.
So what to do to achieve proper results for paging?

My idea to solve this is so far to paginate over simplified data the paging should be able to handle correctly:

- create a table containing the result for all categories and languages and access it with an extra entity.
  The disadvantage is, that I would have to update this table every time a change is done in the for connected tables.

Would you suggest another solution to this problem?

I guess 3rd party software like 
https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/releases
or
https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberPagerfantaBundle/releases
are just sitting on top of the ORM pagination and would not fix the underlying problem.

Correct?

This is my code at the moment:

```
    $page = max(0, $request->query->getInt('page', 0));
    $pageRequest = new PageRequest($itemsPerPage, $page);

    $query = $this->em->createQuery(
        'SELECT sc, sd
          FROM NamiApiCoreBundle:Content sc
          JOIN sc.categoryContents scc
          JOIN sc.descriptions sd
          JOIN sd.language sl
            WHERE
            sc.id = scc.content AND
            scc.category = :id AND
            scc.enabled = 1 AND
            sc.id = sd.content AND
            sd.language = sl.id AND
            sd.description != \'\' AND
            sl.iso = :lang
            ORDER BY scc.priority ASC, sc.id DESC'
    )
        ->setFirstResult($pageRequest->getOffset())
        ->setParameter('lang', $lang)
        ->setParameter('id', $categoryId)
        ->useResultCache(true, $this->cache_lifetime);


    if ($itemsPerPage > 0) {
        $query->setMaxResults($pageRequest->getSize());
    }

    $paginator = new Paginator($query);
```

Comment: Did you try the default doctrine Paginator, described in the 1st link in your question? The quote is not for this Paginator, but using setFirstResults and setMaxResults of a query builder without any paginator.

Comment: ah you think if I would split up the results manually it should work? But what use would be the paginator then?

And yes I use this methods. I add the code with the original query in my question description.

Comment: The code for the Paginator looks good. I think these conditions "sc.id = scc.content", "sc.id = sd.content" and "sd.language = sl.id" are not needed.

Comment: Why do you think they are not necessary? They are the join conditions.

Comment: Doctrine will construct these conditions through the relations. Get the sql produced by geQuery()->getSql() and you should see this

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try and give feedback.